# Как поступить с классом с большим количеством строк

Tags: java

Такая задача: автоматизирую через `Sikulix` тесты для одного приложения. Существует куча картинок с именами (`String`). Эти имена указываются везде в параметрах методов, например `screen.click("image001")`.  Вставлять все время стринги может привести к опечатками и прочим неудобствам, потому хотелось бы создать отдельный класс, где будут приведены имена всех картинок.

Поиск картинок осуществляться не должен. Если делать все `final`, то коллеги настаивают, чтобы имена констант были большими. Но все скрипты будут тогда выглядеть сплошь из апперкейса.

Как можно было бы реализовать такую идею?

Пример:

```
Class Image {
    String image1 = "image1";
}

Class Test {
    Screen screen = new Screen();
    screen.click(Image.image1);
}
```

Comment: Правильно настаивают. Ибо CodeStyle

Comment: Думаю, что если набор строк меняться не будет, то лучше сделать перечисление.